# "The prince has chosen his wife for a week" - Does this sentence sound fine?

Tags: perfect-constructions, past-vs-past-perfect

My friend and I are discussing the following task from our English exercise book.

> Finish each of the following sentences in such a way that it means the
>   same as the sentence printed before it.
>
> **The prince began choosing his wife a week ago.**
>   => The prince has ___.

My friend wrote her answer as below:

> The prince has chosen his wife for a week.

For me, her sentence sounds awkward because 'to have chosen' is an action that seems to happen very quickly, not over a period of time. So, I suggested another sentence to my friend:

> The prince has not decided his wife for a week

Is my explanation correct and if my rewritten sentence doesn't sound fine, please could you suggest a better one?

Comment: The prince **has been choosing** his wife for a week.

Comment: And you can begin the sentence with "For a week", *For a week now the prince has been choosing his wife.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, both sentences sounds like the prince already has many wives. In the first sentence by your friend, it sounds like the prince has decided on a wife for that specific week as in he has many wives and this particular woman will be with him for that week.

In your sentence it sounds like the prince is having difficulty choosing which of his wives to be his wife of the week.

I believe the sentence you could be looking for is:

> The prince has been choosing his wife for a week.

You would have to cross this with the material you have already studied though.